# Worklight data synchronization

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.app

We're currently working on a Worklight project using Dojo (more specifically `dojox/app`). We managed to create a basic example with a store, model, controller and a view. However, now we want to connect this to our Worklight adapter.

What is the best approach in connecting a Dojox/app application to the backend? We were thinking about feeding our store with the data from the Worklight adapter, however, we need to do all CRUD operations and our data should be in sync with the server because multiple users might be working at the same item.

The best general solution I can think about is using a `JsonRest` store, but we're using the `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` function that calls our adapter, so we're not directly using the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We found a solution by using the `WL.JSONStore` from WorkLight. The API of it isn't compatible with the `dojo/store` API (logically since it wasn't meant to be), but we wrote a `dojo/store` API based proxy class which does nothing more than translating and forwarding calls to the `WL.JSONStore`.

Comment: You should consider [open sourcing](http://www.apache.org/legal/src-headers.html#headers) the proxy class you wrote (i.e. post it here or in a quick [gist](https://gist.github.com/)). 

I'm sure other people doing JSONStore+dojo/store/JsonRest may benefit from it. I know not everyone likes or is able to open source their code, ignore this message if that's the case.

Comment: @cnandreu we were planning to do so but at the final moment we decided to move away from the JSONStore because it's only supported on iOS and Android (other operating systems are on the roadmap if I recall correctly). Now we went back to basics and are using normal invoke procedures and manually do all this stuff.